# Absolute positioning messing with max-width when having two images on top of each other

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/kingPear/pen/vzxgXL

I was creating this survey on codepen and wanted to do this funny thing where I had this dog picture right on top of a cat picture and would have the dog picture fade out to reveal the cat picture. I used **absolute positioning** on the dog and changed the opacity using css animation.

Anyway, I noticed that when I shrunk the window the images were not flexible like the words so I did this:

```
**max-width:100%;**
```

for the dog id and the cat id.

the id's are called #dog and #cat.

the cat one works just fine because its position:relative but the dog one is not working because properly its position absolute. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```css
#number-label {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

#number {
  width: 142.5px;
}

#dog {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: toCat;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#cat {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

@keyframes toCat {
  100% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
  background: #FFC986;
}

main {
  font-family: Chalkboard;
  line-height: 170%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: -70px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  100% {
    width: auto;
    color: #E87900;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}

#description {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#submit {
  background-color: #FFC94D;
  border-radius: 30%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFC94D;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 230px;
  animation-name: submit-retract;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#submit:hover {
  border-color: #E87900;
  animation-name: submit-bounce;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#submit:active {
  border-color: #E87900;
  background-color: #E87900;
}

@keyframes submit-bounce {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}

@keyframes submit-retract {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img id="dog" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img id="cat" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCaGYUIfdy4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <h1 id="title">Cat Survey</h1>
  <p id="description"> A survey to see the impact a cat can how on you!</p>
  <br>
  <form id="survey-form">

    <label for="name" id="name-label">* Name:
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
          </label>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email-label">* Email:
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
          </label>
    <br>
    <label for="number" id="number-label">Age:
            <input type="number" min=1 max=100 id="number" placeholder="Enter your age">
            <br>
            
            <p> What best describes your life right now?</p>
            <select id="dropdown">
              <option disabled value selected="select">Select an option</option>
              <option value="happy">happy</option>
              <option value="sad">sad</option>
              <option value="average">average</option>
              <option value="extra">extraordinary</option>
            </select>
            
            <p>Do you think having a cat could make things better?</p>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=1> Yes
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=2> No
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=3> Maybe
            </label>

    <p>Do you find cats to be charming?</p>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=1> No they are freeloaders.<br>
             <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=2> Yes, they are very interesting creatures<br>
             <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=3> I am indifferent towards them
            </label>

    <p> Select all the qualities you look for in a cat:</p>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=1> Young
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=2> Furry
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=3> Big eyes
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=4> Foreign
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=5> None, I dont want one.
            </label>

    <p> If a cat was about to be hit by a car, select all of things you would do:</p>
    <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=1> I would jump in a shield the cat! (bad idea).<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=2> I would let it get hit... and go help it and call animal care immediately.<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=3> I would let it get hit and run away.<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=4> I would try to resurrect the cat using alchemy!<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=5> I would cry and run back home and hug my dog :)<br>
            </label>

    <p>I hope this helped you decide how impactful a cat can be on your life!<br>(It probably didn't) Tell me what I did wrong in the text area!</p>
    <label for="comments">
              <textarea id="comments" style="width:500px; height:100px;" placeholder="I like dogs..."></textarea>
            </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</main>
```

I also can't seem to make the text area at the bottom of the survey flexible so it would be great if I could get help on that too. But images is what I mainly need help on.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you html is invalide, you cannot have body inside another tag

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh thanks for that! I did find it weird putting the body tag there. But my problem still persists even after deleting those tags.

Comment: yes you will still have issue but this is the first step to do ... and if you can correct the code and post here it will be better that posting a codepen

Comment: @TemaniAfif done

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the `main` element `position:relative` so that the image is positioned relatively to it then you have to consider the padding in the width calculation. For the textarea instead of using `width:500px` use `width:100%;max-width:500px` to avoid the overflow and make it responsive.

And better avoid changing the style of the `body`. You can do this within the `main`:

```css
#number-label {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

#number {
  width: 142.5px;
}

#dog {
  width: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: toCat;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#cat {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

@keyframes toCat {
  100% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

body {
  background: #FFC986;
}

main {
  font-family: Chalkboard;
  line-height: 170%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  max-width:30%;
  margin:auto;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#comments {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  100% {
    width: auto;
    color: #E87900;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}

#description {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#submit {
  background-color: #FFC94D;
  border-radius: 30%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFC94D;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left:20px;
  animation-name: submit-retract;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#submit:hover {
  border-color: #E87900;
  animation-name: submit-bounce;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#submit:active {
  border-color: #E87900;
  background-color: #E87900;
}

@keyframes submit-bounce {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}

@keyframes submit-retract {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img id="dog" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img id="cat" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCaGYUIfdy4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <h1 id="title">Cat Survey</h1>
  <p id="description"> A survey to see the impact a cat can how on you!</p>
  <form id="survey-form">

    <label for="name" id="name-label">* Name:
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
          </label>
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="email-label">* Email:
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
          </label>
    <br>
    <label for="number" id="number-label">Age:
            <input type="number" min=1 max=100 id="number" placeholder="Enter your age">
    </label>            
            <p> What best describes your life right now?</p>
            <select id="dropdown">
              <option disabled value selected="select">Select an option</option>
              <option value="happy">happy</option>
              <option value="sad">sad</option>
              <option value="average">average</option>
              <option value="extra">extraordinary</option>
            </select>
            
            <p>Do you think having a cat could make things better?</p>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=1> Yes
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=2> No
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" value=3> Maybe
            </label>

    <p>Do you find cats to be charming?</p>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=1> No they are freeloaders.<br>
             <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=2> Yes, they are very interesting creatures<br>
             <input type="radio" name="radio2" value=3> I am indifferent towards them
            </label>

    <p> Select all the qualities you look for in a cat:</p>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=1> Young
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=2> Furry
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=3> Big eyes
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=4> Foreign
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value=5> None, I dont want one.
            </label>

    <p> If a cat was about to be hit by a car, select all of things you would do:</p>
    <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=1> I would jump in a shield the cat! (bad idea).<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=2> I would let it get hit... and go help it and call animal care immediately.<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=3> I would let it get hit and run away.<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=4> I would try to resurrect the cat using alchemy!<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value=5> I would cry and run back home and hug my dog :)<br>
            </label>

    <p>I hope this helped you decide how impactful a cat can be on your life!<br>(It probably didn't) Tell me what I did wrong in the text area!</p>
    <label for="comments">
              <textarea id="comments"  placeholder="I like dogs..."></textarea>
            </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</main>
```